# How to get count of documents in a collection?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

If I have a really large number of documents in a collection, can I get the count of documents without having to load entire collection.

```
db.collection('largecollection').get().then(snapshot => {
   length = snapshot.size;
})
```

Comment: You could use a Cloud Function to update a counter each time a doc is added to the collection (as well as each time one is deleted, if necessary)

Comment: I think you might also be interested in this article, [How to count the number of documents in a Firestore collection?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-count-the-number-of-documents-in-a-firestore-collection-3bd0c719978f).

Answer (score 5):

There is no built-in API to get the count of the number of documents in a collection. So by default you'll have to download all documents to count them.

As Renaud commented, the common workaround to this is to keep a separate counter that you update every time a document is added/removed. You could do this from within your app, [updating the counter with a transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/aggregation) every time you add/remove a document. But it's more reliable to do this in a server, such as Cloud Functions for Firebase. For an example of this approach, see [the `functions-samples` repo](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/child-count). While the sample is for the Firebase Realtime Database, the approach is equally applicable to Firestore.

Also see the Firestore documentation section on [distributed counters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/counters).

Answer (score 4):

Be careful counting number of documents for **large collections**. It is a little bit complex with firestore database if you want to have a precalculated counter for every collection.

**Code like this doesn't work in this case:**

```
export const customerCounterListener = 
    functions.firestore.document('customers/{customerId}')
    .onWrite((change, context) => {

    // on create
    if (!change.before.exists && change.after.exists) {
        return firestore
                 .collection('metadatas')
                 .doc('customers')
                 .get()
                 .then(docSnap =>
                     docSnap.ref.set({
                         count: docSnap.data().count + 1
                     }))
    // on delete
    } else if (change.before.exists && !change.after.exists) {
        return firestore
                 .collection('metadatas')
                 .doc('customers')
                 .get()
                 .then(docSnap =>
                     docSnap.ref.set({
                         count: docSnap.data().count - 1
                     }))
    }

    return null;
});
```

The reason is because every cloud firestore trigger has to be idempotent, as firestore documentation say: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events#limitations_and_guarantees

### Solution

So, in order to prevent multiple executions of your code, you need to manage with events and transactions. This is my particular way to handle large collection counters:

```
const executeOnce = (change, context, task) => {
    const eventRef = firestore.collection('events').doc(context.eventId);

    return firestore.runTransaction(t =>
        t
         .get(eventRef)
         .then(docSnap => (docSnap.exists ? null : task(t)))
         .then(() => t.set(eventRef, { processed: true }))
    );
};

const documentCounter = collectionName => (change, context) =>
    executeOnce(change, context, t => {
        // on create
        if (!change.before.exists && change.after.exists) {
            return t
                    .get(firestore.collection('metadatas')
                    .doc(collectionName))
                    .then(docSnap =>
                        t.set(docSnap.ref, {
                            count: ((docSnap.data() && docSnap.data().count) || 0) + 1
                        }));
        // on delete
        } else if (change.before.exists && !change.after.exists) {
            return t
                     .get(firestore.collection('metadatas')
                     .doc(collectionName))
                     .then(docSnap =>
                        t.set(docSnap.ref, {
                            count: docSnap.data().count - 1
                        }));
        }

        return null;
    });
```

Use cases here:

```
/**
 * Count documents in articles collection.
 */
exports.articlesCounter = functions.firestore
    .document('articles/{id}')
    .onWrite(documentCounter('articles'));

/**
 * Count documents in customers collection.
 */
exports.customersCounter = functions.firestore
    .document('customers/{id}')
    .onWrite(documentCounter('customers'));
```

As you can see, the key to prevent multiple execution is the property called **eventId** in the context object. If the function has been handled many times for the same event, the event id will be the same in all cases. Unfortunately, you must have "events" collection in your database.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46554091/cloud-firestore-collection-count/61050621#61050621