# Firestore rules on counters

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

How do i force my rule to know that the new value is equal the value before + 1 ???

tried:

```
allow write: if request.resource.data.counter == resource.data.counter + 1
```

what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: How are you testing that this rule doesn't work the way you expect? What's the entire rule, and what's your code to exercise it?

Comment: That rule looks fine at first glance. As Doug asked: what code are you using to test this?

Comment: Lol guys, i'm just trying to increment my database. I have a counter of commentaries, for each commentarie, my total_commentaries is updated by a value equals -> old value + 1, which is what i'm passing to the rule. But i get block.

Before putting the rule, it was allow write, after putting rule, got blocked, so yes, a simple test

Comment: Please avoid using security rules for incrementing counters. Instead, use Transactions to update data and keep it consistent. https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions

Comment: Whaat?? Kkk, security rules are just to protect fields updated by transactions.

Comment: here is my post - https://stackoverflow.com/a/62368061/271450