# Why do I get "Expected catch() or return"-error when trying to connect to firestore via cloud-function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I use google cloud firestore with a certain amount of collections.
I am trying to write a google cloud function that returns the number of collections in this firestore upon http-request.

So I wrote the following `index.js`-file drawing from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46554091/firebase-firestore-collection-count):

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.queryForData = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    var db = admin.firestore();
    db.get().then(snap => {
        response.status(200).send({length: snap.size});
        })
    });
```

After deploying, I get this error:

[image]

The strange thing is: When I delete the line var `db = admin.firestore();` I get the very same error. So I suspect, that I am not correctly connecting to firestore at all.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That looks like a linter warning, not a runtime error.

Comment: @Bergi It is a linter warning indeed.

Answer (score 2):

As explained on the [official video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7IkUgCLr5oA&t=1s&list=PLl-K7zZEsYLkPZHe41m4jfAxUi0JjLgSM&index=3) on HTTP Cloud Function, you should add a `catch()` block to your Cloud Function, as follows:

```
exports.queryForData = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    var db = admin.firestore();
    db.get()
    .then(snap => {
       response.status(200).send({length: snap.size});
       //Or response.send({length: snap.size});
    })
    .catch(error => {
       console.log(error);
       response.status(500).send(error);
    })
});
```

But, in addition, if I am not mistaken, **there is (another) error in your Cloud Function**: you do `db.get()` but there is not `get()` method for the [Firestore service interface](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Firestore). You should call the [`get()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference#get) method on a [`CollectionReference`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference), since you are using the `size()` method on the returned [`QuerySnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot) (i.e. `snap`):

```
exports.queryForData = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    var db = admin.firestore();
    db.collection('collectionId').get()
    .then(snap => {
       response.status(200).send({length: snap.size});
       //Or response.send({length: snap.size});
    })
    .catch(error => {
       console.log(error);
       response.status(500).send(error);
    })
});
```

---

Note that you could also call `get()` on a [`DocumentReference`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference).

Comment: This gives me: "Each then() should return a value or throw promise/always-return". Could it be that the function does not find the firestore at all? This is my suspicion.

Comment: The code is correct from a Firebase perspective (as said in the answer, please refer to the Firebase video) but you get a lint error, as other answers have noted. I don't know how to solve this. You may follow @Dennis Alund proposal to add a `return null;` after the `response.send()...` but I have the feeling this return will never be reached since the Firebase doc/video explains that the `response.send()...` indicates to the platform that the Cloud Function is done. **It would be interesting to have the feedback of Doug Stevenson or Puf**.

Comment: Also note that in the case of an HTTP Cloud Function the video shows that you don't need to return the initial promise returned by the `get()` method (while it is a must for background triggered Cloud Functions).

Comment: This answer works for me, when I use 'firebase serve --only functions'. I get the same error though, when I use 'firebase deploy --only functions' or 'firebase deploy'. Therefore I suppose, that there must be something wrong with my setup?

Answer (score 1):

You need to return a value after the`Promise` finishes, in your case you can do the following:

```
exports.queryForData = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
var db = admin.firestore();
return db.get().then(snap => {
     response.status(200).send({length: snap.size});
    })
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Now I don't get the error in 7:16 anymore. But I still get the same error in 7:2.

Comment: Deploy again the function

Comment: Add a catch then `.catch(e => {
        console.log(e);
        response.sendStatus(404);` you should already add a catch maybe the response was failed

Comment: Try to explicitly return a `null` value or place a return in front of the `response.status()...` statement. The linter probably doesn't like that the promise is implicitly resolved to `undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

The call to Firestore is asynchronous and you must make sure that you are managing the lifecycle of your cloud function for that.

The [documentation states the following](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions)

> - Resolve functions that perform **asynchronous** processing (also known as
>     "background functions") by returning a JavaScript promise.
> - Terminate **HTTP functions** with res.redirect(), res.send(), or res.end().
> - Terminate a **synchronous** function with a return; statement.

You can fix this by simply adding a return statement to your `db.get()`. And also, to get rid of your lint error, you should return a value from inside your handler. You can either return `null` or just return the `response.send()`

By omitting a return statement, [it will implicitly resolve to `undefined`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then#Return_value) ... which probably why you get the warning.

```
exports.queryForData = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    var db = admin.firestore();
    return db.get().then(snap => {
        response.status(200).send({length: snap.size});
        return null;
        })
    });
```

The returned promise from `db.get()` will ensure that the function stays alive until your HTTP response has been sent and also terminates the function after the promise is resolved.

By not finalizing your functions properly, they might run until they timeout. See this video: https://youtu.be/xu5A1seU6PU?t=233