# How to count the number of documents in a firebase collection using dart

Tags: firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am using flutter and firestore and I need a way to count the number of documents within a certain collection
"counting TestUsers documents = 3 "
Thank you
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rOeKJ.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cloud Firestore collection count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46554091/cloud-firestore-collection-count)

Comment: Thanks but I already tried them and they are not working

Comment: I think you might also be interested in this article, [How to count the number of documents in a Firestore collection?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-count-the-number-of-documents-in-a-firestore-collection-3bd0c719978f).

Comment: @Nouf: "they are not working" is hard to help with. If you tried the approach in the linked articles, edit your question to show what you tried. Without a [minimal repro](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), your question is going to be marked as a duplicate of the existing ones on counting documents, since there is nothing specific to Dart/Flutter about the process.