# how can I display my total orders using react and stored in firebase?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

i have ordered firestore collection in firebase then i want to count all orders display as a single number not retrieve the data

I have tried something but totally doesn't work so if you have some solution please help me

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cloud Firestore collection count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46554091/cloud-firestore-collection-count)

Comment: See https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/aggregation-queries. If that doesn't work for you, edit your question to show the [minimal, complete/standalone code that any of us can run to reproduce where you got stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).