# GCP Firestore collection count in python

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I've read this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46554091/cloud-firestore-collection-count), but I still don't know how to count the number of documents in a collection with Python.

My code :

```py
job = db.collection(u'netcollect_jobs').document('48c94805-1dab-4325-a927-f22f9c9b635d')
coll = job.collection('job_result_per_device')
coll_count = coll.count().get()
print(coll_count)
print(finished_device[0][0].value)
```

output :

```
[[<Aggregation alias=field_1, value=25003, readtime=2023-04-17 13:52:27.813282+00:00>]]
25003
```

Ok, I found the number of documents (25003), but it's weird to access it like I did (i.e `[0][0].value`). I feel like what I did is not 'official' (not recommanded).
On documentation, I didn't find anything, neither in the [github repo](https://github.com/googleapis/python-firestore/tree/main/google/cloud/firestore_v1).

What's the best solution for achieve this ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. That `25003` in your output looks like it's the document count. Is that not what you expected?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen `25003` is my count, but it's weird to access to this data through the `[0][0].value`. Is it 'official' ? It will always works ?

Comment: From these docs: [1](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/firestore/latest/aggregation), [2](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/firestore/latest/google.cloud.firestore_v1.types.RunAggregationQueryResponse) and [3](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/firestore/latest/google.cloud.firestore_v1.types.AggregationResult) it seems correct.