# How to count the documents in a firestore collection without retrieving the entire collection?

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using the following code to retrieve a random document from a firestore collection:

```
    collection = db.collection('Items')
    total_docs = collection.count().get()[0][0].value

    random_offset = random.randint(0, total_docs - 1)
    random_doc = collection.limit(1).offset(random_offset).get()[0]
```

I noticed that this code produces a lot of read-usage and discovered that the entire collection is read when counting the documents.

Hence my question: **How can retrieve the count of documents in a collection without reading the entire collection?**

And if this isn't possible: **How can I randomly retrieve a document from a collection without specifying how many documents the collection contains?**

Many thanks!

Comment: `collection.count()` doesn't read every document in the collection.  See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46554091/cloud-firestore-collection-count

Comment: It's not the `count()` statement that causes those reads, but the `offset(random_offset)` that you use. Currently `offset()` reads all documents that you ask it to skip, it just doesn't return them - and. you get charged for those reads.

Comment: When it comes to counting, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-count-the-number-of-documents-in-a-firestore-collection-3bd0c719978f) will help.

Answer (score 0):

One approach you can take is normalizing your collection into a single doc. Essentially, you create a new doc within `Items` called `_index` or something of the sort.

This can have a field called `count` which you increment/decrement with [`FieldValue.increment`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#increment_a_numeric_value) whenever you modify any other document in your collection. (Alternatively, you could omit this field and use `len(keys)`.

You can have another field called `keys` which you modify with [`FieldValue.arrayUnion`/`FieldValue.arrayRemove`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array) whenever a new document is created/removed based on the doc ID.

While this adds another write operation for each new doc, it also gives you  a much simpler process for reading in a large list of doc IDs.

From here, you can read this index doc and pick a random item.

```
/Items
  /_index
    - count: 2
    - keys: ["docId123", "docId456"]
  /docId123
    - foo: "bar"
  /docId456
    - foo: "baz"
```