# Counting documents in firestore collection with react-redux-firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, redux, redux-firestore

I need to count documents in firestore collection and I saw this article https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/aggregation-queries

However the project I am working on currently uses react-redux-firebase instead of using API described in the article above directly.

So, when I try

```js
await firestore.collection('items').count().get();
```

I get error

> count is not a function

Is there a way to use this firestore functionality from react-redux-firebase or somehow get reference to original API methods from within react-redux-firebase?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cloud Firestore collection count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46554091/cloud-firestore-collection-count). Make sure you're following the **web** guides and not the Node.js ones