# How to get count of documents in a collection in firestore

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

i have a collection "Store"

in that having number of documents

how i get the count of documents in that collection.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe there is no built in method for this but you can try this! First get all the documents in a List and then just get the size.

```
  db.collection("Store")
    .get()
    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
               int count = 0;
                for (DocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                   count++;
                }
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
            }
        }
    });
```

Src:[get data with Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data)

Comment: i am getting errors at ApiFuture and future.get()

Comment: @Ramakrishna edited, accidenetly chose java code for query instead of android appearantly this should work, db is your database instance, count is your document count , or if you don't get smth check the link with docs

Comment: Don't need to run loop use this task.getResult().size()

Comment: Can you help me with this question please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54653836/how-to-use-query-in-firebase-firestore

Comment: this approach is not cost-efficient. It will read all document. Why read all documents when we need just count.

Comment: @VikashSharma ask Google, as the answer states there is no api for this that is provided out of the box

Comment: @Rainmaker this approach is very expensive. We should add transaction for counting documents. This way we won't be reading all the documents all the time just to get count.

Comment: @VikashSharma if I am sure what you mean, please post your suggestion as a stand alone answer so It can help people if it is more optimized u feel

Comment: @Rainmaker https://stackoverflow.com/a/62270141/7011829

Comment: In that case I will have to pay for each reading returned even if I do nothing in the snapshots besides counting?

Comment: @DjongaNelsonLontrowski yes, but even if there was a api to just get count how do you think it would work? It would still be some resource used to get the number of rows in the table on disk. Disk operation (if you write something, read or count rows) all have some cost.

Comment: Is there a way for finding out in kotlin?