# How to Count Number of documents in a collection in Firestore Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

In flutter we use the `Querysnapshot.documents.length` to fetch number of documents?

Similarly , How can we can do it in Java Android Studio

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Already Answered [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47768208/how-to-get-count-of-documents-in-a-collection-in-firestore)

No built in Method Actually, We have to count the documents using for loop

Answer (score 2):

Instead of looping just get size

```
db.collection("Store")
    .get()
    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
               Log.d(TAG, "Size is", task.getResult().size());
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
            }
        }
    });
```