# How to get a number of document from an index to other index by query in Firestore

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to make pagination with data what is stored in cloud `Firestore`. It looks like that:

[image]

Note, It is different from load more or infinite loading. Lets assume that, When user click at **pager 3**, I need to make a request to my `Firestore` to get 25 items from position 50 to 75(25 items per page).

I should do like that:

```
db.collection("cities")
    .orderBy("population")
      .startAfter(lastVisible)
        .limit(25);
```

The problem here is I do not have `lastVisible`. I know we can get `lastVisible` by getting first 50 items but it is so dumb because if I do like that, why don't
I just get first 75 items and filter what we want in client.

The question is: How to get a number of items from an index to other index by query in `Firestore`? 
Any help would be appreciated! Thanks so much!

Comment: Did you find a solution? I need a solution for a problem like this.

Comment: @JancoBoscan: Sadly, I did not find the solution. I think we have to use infinite loading instead

Comment: ok = (, today I gave up and I removed my angular material 2 paginator and I changed it to a "load more" button. thanks for your answer

Answer (score 5):

**Updated answer:**

You can maintain an array of size as the decided count of your pages. Value at each index would denote the `startAt` field value of your `cities` field.

Additionally you will also maintain a count of your documents. This will help you give the limit value (`count / numberOfPages`).

You will maintain both of these with help of cloud function triggers, as already described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46553314/how-to-get-a-count-of-number-of-documents-in-a-collection-with-cloud-firestore).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Distributed Counters is new to me. I will take a look at it and comeback with the result

Comment: You're welcome. Distributed Counters is just a technique that works around the limitation of firestore that you cannot edit a firestore document more than once per second. So if you know your 'items' count will likely change more than once per second, storing the count in one document will be a problem. So, you solve this by using several sub-counters (and then calculate the total count by aggregating the values of the sub-counters every time).

Comment: Lets assume that, i have total of items = 100. I will show 25 items per page so will have 4 pages. But how do i determine `startAfter` (or `endBefore`) for every page?

Comment: You know you have 100 items. You know you have decided to have 4 pages. You now simply save an integer array (let's say, denoting endBefore): [25, 50, 75, 100]. This array now contains the endBefore values at indices corresponding to you page number.
You can possibly even maintain this array in your count document directly.

Comment: Assume that, i have all these data above in my hand. But i can not get 25 items from position 50 to 75 because i do not know the item at position 50 nor 75. The only way is get all 100 items and do the `splice`.

Comment: I thought that the whole point was not having to retrieve all 100 items in the client if all you need is to show items 50-74 on page 3.

Comment: Ya. It is exactly my problem because the items will be very big number and get all items will take the quota, the time and the performance

Comment: Yeah. So do as discussed above. Maintain an array of endBefore values. Now simply get this array and use `db.collection("cities")...` query to get exactly the range of items that is suitable for the page.

Answer (score 0):

**Classic Pagination** is great in combination with tables, unfortunately this is not well supported Firestore at the time.
[image: Classic Pagination]

I would suggest you to switch your approach of limiting data to **Infinte-Scroll**

[image: Infinite Scrolling]

In combination with powerful filtering options you can archive even a better user experience

You can find a handy example in Firebase documentation:   https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors#paginate-a-query

**More Information:**
https://uxplanet.org/ux-infinite-scrolling-vs-pagination-1030d29376f1

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but i just want to find the solution for Pagination because it is the best choice in my case.

Answer (score 0):

You can push the document id to an array and query the collections using

```
firebase.firestore().collection("users").where(firebase.firestore.FieldPath.documentId(), "in", array)
```

you can further retrieve the array where array's index is between(pages*10 and pages-1*10) where page is your current page